# Dockerized Elasticsearch - Scripting not working

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I have a running elasticsearch on production and I have the following filter in one of my queries

```
"filter": {
  "script": {
    "script": "doc['today_count'].value == doc['yesterday_count'].value"
  }
}
```

And is working because I had to include this directives on my elasticsearch.yml file.

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
```

Now I'm building a dockerized environment and elasticsearch container is complaining of the query

```
ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search]
and lang [groovy] are disabled];
```

But I have tried the following configurations
Dockerfile:

```
FROM elasticsearch:2.3.3
COPY elasticsearch.yml /etc/elasticsearch/
```

elasticsearch.yml:

```
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
```

And elastic still complaining by the same way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with

```
script.inline: true 
 script.indexed: true
```

instead of `on` ?